# Is there a good reason to prefer unsafe approaches versus MemoryMarshal.AsMemory() in the RARE occasions when string mutability is needed?

Tags: c#, unsafe

Whilst rare, there are scenarios when I've found the need to have literal mutable strings - more so since the introduction of `Memory<char>`, since basically strings work better for dictionary keys, and if you're careful, you can use unsafe code to copy characters into buffer strings to enable low-allocation when checking for cache entries keyed on string versions of prior `Memory<char>` instances.

So we're already using unsafe code.

With that in mind, I recently discovered that this works:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

...

private void ChangeSomeString(string original, int changeAt) 
{
    // This is a toy example. Please assume I have full ownership of original, and it 
    // has not been interned - e.g. created via new String('\0', 100);
    var mutable = MemoryMarshal.AsMemory(original.AsMemory());
    mutable.Span[changeAt] = '_';
}
```

Are there any reasons to prefer the more esoteric approach of working directly with pointers (which requires someone to know what `fixed` means in the future etc) over this one - especially in the context of the MSDN docs saying very clearly that you SHOULD NOT CHANGE memory made read/write via this API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.asmemory?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: This question was asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53167132/c-sharp-modify-interned-string-through-span-memory-and-memorymarshal

Comment: This is really interesting (I started with C++ decades ago and sometimes miss the low level stuff). Personally I would think it would be better to use `fixed` so that future you or others will have NO DOUBT about what you're doing. As it stands, you're sort of exploiting a behavior of the framework that isn't intended or at least isn't encouraged. And I could see a future breaking change preventing it. But otherwise it seems like it's functionally equivalent. Though I'm curious about one thing - does your assembly have to have Unsafe enabled to compile this?

Comment: To play devil's advocate a bit: `string` isn't doing anything in Equals or GetHashCode which you can't implement yourself for `Memory<char>` (although you may have to copy some code off https://source.dot.net), and that will avoid the need to copy things in and out of mutable strings

Comment: @PeterMoore Nope - compiles fine, and is treated as "safe". Probably the obvious cockups which unsafe is intended to localize (i.e. indexing a pointer beyond allocated memory or the like) are prevented by the `Span<>` API in general - leaving only the less obvious ones like overwriting a string that was interned by mistake.

Comment: @canton7 There isn't, but I believe the initial attempt was to use `Span<char>` instead of string (versus `Memory<char>`). There IS a problem with writing an `IEqualityComparer<Span<T>>`, because then you have to use a ref struct in an interface, which is forbidden. I believe the other motivation was avoiding calling .ToString() when I really _did_ need a string (and instead effectively interning the result of another call). There's something wrong when using `Span<char>` costs memory instead of saving it!

Comment: @tobriand interesting. Perhaps it's not actually "Unsafe" (capital U) because I assume `Memory` is still bounds checking, and still operating under the CLR generally, whereas `fixed` of course is not? If so, then using pointers should have significantly better performance.